# Creating Report view table of selected items plus "Other" in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, greatest-n-per-group

From list of all countries and their land area

| Country | Area |
| --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | 652230 |
| Albania | 28748 |
| Algeria | 2381741 |
| American Samoa | 199 |
| ... | ... |

I would like to create the following table and slicer.

[Report view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkONg.png)

The table would respond to Slicer. In which you could select one of the given options. The table would then display the selected countries, plus a row with the sum of the area of the other countries. Please, no guidance on how to proceed.
I tried using the following measurements, but it didn't help.

```
Other = IF(ISFILTERED(Word[Country]), Word[Area],0)

Other = CALCULATE(SUM(Word[Area]), ALLSELECTED(Word[Country]))

TotalArea = SUM(Word[Area])

RankArea = RANKX(ALL(Word[Country]),Word[TotalArea])

TopSelect = SUMX(TOPN(10,SUMMARIZE(Word,Word[Area],"TopN", SUM(Word[Area])),[TopN], DESC),[TopN])

Top5 = IF ([RankArea] <= 5,Word[TotalArea], IF(HASONEVALUE(Word[Country]), IF(VALUES(Word[Country]) = "Other", SUMX ( FILTER ( ALL ( Word[Country] ), [RankArea] > 3 ), [TotalArea]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is to have a "translator" table in between country and the slicer table. This works when the mapping between each slicer option and each country is static (there are no other filter/context options that would change which countries are assigned to each slicer). There should be a bi-directional filter between Word[Country] and Translator[Country], and a single directional filter between Translator[Slicer] and Slicer[Slicer]. We want the output to look like this:

[image]

We can do this dynamically by appending (`UNION()`) interpretation tables for each slicer option.

```
UNION(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        Word,
        "Label",IF(RANK(Skip,Word[Area],ORDERBY(Word[Area],Desc)<=5,Word[Country],"Other"),
        "Slicer","Top 5"
    ),
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        Word,
        "Label",IF(RANK(Skip,Word[Area],ORDERBY(Word[Area],Desc)<=10,Word[Country],"Other"),
        "Slicer","Top 10"
    ),
    TOPN(
        COUNTROWS(ALL(Word))-5,
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            Word,
            "Label",Word[Country],
            "Slicer","All Excl. Top 5"
        ),
        Word[Area],ASC
    ),
    TOPN(
        COUNTROWS(ALL(Word))-10,
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            Word,
            "Label",Word[Country],
            "Slicer","All Excl. Top 10"
        ),
        Word[Area],ASC
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is "skip" in RANK? Did you really mean RANK and not RANKX?

Comment: Skip means ties will be given the same rank, and the next record will "skip" the tied ranks, e.g. {1,2,3,3,3,6...} Vs dense would give you {1,2,3,3,3,4...}. I believe rank should be better than rankx here. Rank is smart to the current context, vs rankx would need you to explicitly reconstruct the existing type context, which is less clean and slower.